# If statement within Lambda function?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-3.0, lambda

This may be quite simple but I'm rather new to Lambda's so bear with me.

I have a function that uses a Lambda function to recurse.
The main function receives a bool telling it to include certain information or not within the lambda.

The function is designed to write out a custom class to XML - I think the code is pretty self explanitory.

At the moment I have overcome the problem using a simple if statement, but it feels ugly so wondered if anyone knew a better way?

```
        private XElement ErrorListToXml(ErrorList el, bool outputTagsOnly)
    {
        // Need to declare in advance to call within the lambda.
        Func<ErrorType, XElement> recursiveGenerator = null;

        if (outputTagsOnly)
            recursiveGenerator = error => new XElement
                (error.Name,
                 error.ChildErrors.Select(recursiveGenerator));
        else
            recursiveGenerator = error => new XElement
          (error.Name,
          new XAttribute("Ignore", error.Filter),
           error.ChildErrors.Select(recursiveGenerator));


        var element = new XElement
                   ("ErrorList",
                    ChildErrors.Select(recursiveGenerator));

        Console.WriteLine(element);

        return element;
    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

mquander's solution can be improved slightly to reduce duplication. You can use the fact that you can pass in `null` an element in the XElement constructor content, and it gets ignored. We can therefore move the condition further in:

```
Func<ErrorType, XElement> recursiveGenerator = null;    
recursiveGenerator = (error => new XElement(error.Name,
            outputTagsOnly ? null : new XAttribute("Ignore", error.Filter),
            error.ChildErrors.Select(recursiveGenerator));

var element = new XElement("ErrorList", ChildErrors.Select(recursiveGenerator));
```

Comment: Ahhh, this is how I originally tried to do it but didn't realise you could pass null either. Thanks

Answer (score 9):

You can make a decision between values of the same type in a lambda pretty easily:

```
customer => flag ? customer.Name : customer.Address
```

You can use an if statement in a lambda with a little more effort:

```
customer =>
{
  if (flag)
    return customer.Name
  else
    return customer.Address
}
```

Neither of these helps your method greatly.

Answer (score 6):

You could move the "if" statement inside the lambda function safely, if you preferred:

```
Func<ErrorType, XElement> recursiveGenerator = null;

recursiveGenerator = (error =>
    outputTagsOnly
        ? new XElement(error.Name,
                       error.ChildErrors.Select(recursiveGenerator));
        : new XElement(error.Name, new XAttribute("Ignore", error.Filter),
                       error.ChildErrors.Select(recursiveGenerator)));

var element = new XElement("ErrorList", ChildErrors.Select(recursiveGenerator));
```

Other than that, there doesn't seem to be any trivial way to simplify what you've got.

(P.S. When it looks ugly, put some lipstick on that pig by pretty-printing it ;)

Comment: Here performance is somewhat worse than in the original code: you check the flag outputTagsOnly on generation of _every_ node, while it's totally not necessary, you can check it once. (Of course for the small input data its insignificant)

Comment: Yes, I realized that, but the flag check is so vanishingly insignificant compared to the overhead of actually constructing XML elements that I think it is of absolutely zero importance compared to readability.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can do this, but end of the day it's still an if:

```
                recursiveGenerator = error => outputTagsOnly ? 
                   new XElement(error.Name,error.ChildErrors.Select(recursiveGenerator)
              : 
              new XElement(error.Name,new XAttribute("Ignore", error.Filter), 
             error.ChildErrors.Select(recursiveGenerator);
```

Comment: Cheers mate, mquander pipped you to the post. I know it is still an if I was just trying to find a more elegant way.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to decompose your problem into two different ones:

1. How to build a tree from errors structure.
2. What to put into the tree nodes.

Then the code will look like:

```
        private XElement ErrorListToXml(ErrorList el, bool outputTagsOnly)
        {
            // Need to declare in advance to call within the lambda.
            Func<ErrorType, XElement> treeGenerator = null;
            Func<ErrorType, object[]> elementParametersGenerator = null;

            treeGenerator = error => new XElement
                (error.Name,
                elementParametersGenerator(error));

            if(outputTagsOnly)
                elementParametersGenerator = error => 
                    new object[] {error.ChildErrors.Select(treeGenerator)};
            else
                elementParametersGenerator = error => 
                    new object[] { new XAttribute("Ignore", error.Filter), error.ChildErrors.Select(treeGenerator) };

            var element = new XElement
                       ("ErrorList",
                        ChildErrors.Select(treeGenerator));

            Console.WriteLine(element);

            return element;
        }
```

Not any significantly better in this particular case, but it's a more general approach.